# Python Join multiple lists into a string with %

Tags: python, list, join

I have two lists of strings that I want to join into string. Basically if I have two lists:

`name = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']`

`link = ['Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3']`

and I want to insert them into a string, such as one below:

`<a href="%s">%s`

Is this possible to do using join or do I need to use a for loop?

Comment: Why use `%`? Unless you're on an old version of python, you should be using `.format()`

Comment: Depending on the application (i.e., if this is part of a web app or CGI script) it may be better to use a template language such as [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). Also, it'd be better to name those variables `names` and `links`, because they're containers which hold a *plurality* of items.

Comment: @Haidro what's `.format()`? I actually haven't come across this before.

Comment: @user1998511 Here's a link to the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
['<a href="%s">%s' % (n, l) for (n, l) in zip(name, link)]
```

But don't forget to encode `n` and `l` appropriately in order to prevent security issues.

Comment: Yes, though note you don't need the parens around the second `(n, l)` above.

Answer (score 0):

@Ignacio's answer is a great one for this application.

Depending on the intended use, you might instead need to create one string with the right number of placeholders.

```
from itertools import chain, izip
name = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']    
link = ['Link1', 'Link2', 'Link3']

args = [i for i in chain.from_iterable(izip(name, link))]
placeholder = ''.join(["<a href=%s>%s"] * len (name))
# combined to make '<a href=%s>%s<a href=%s>%s<a href=%s>%s'
print placeholder % tuple(args)
```

The two useful tricks (a) to use list multiplication to duplicate the placeholder string as needed and (b) remember that % requires a tuple argument.   This is a common pattern when expanding lists of placeholders